# rendering component after post method call

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I'm creating a mern app where i'm able to display, create, edit, and delete projects from an express API.

so far I can get the data to be displayed but when I try to create a new project, the data aren't displayed and aren't rendered. The post method sends OK 200 response and displays the data in redux-logger but not in components until i refersh the page then the new project is displayed alongside with other previous ones, and I'm wondering how I can render the new projects in the Project components

Projects //where i render the project

```
class Projects extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
        super(props)
    this.state={
                showForm:false,
                projects:this.props.projects
              }

              this.showCreateProjectForm=this.showCreateProjectForm.bind(this)


    }


showCreateProjectForm(){
    this.setState({showForm:!this.state.showForm})
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div>
      <Button name="create project" 
              title="Create A Project"
              onClickAction={this.showCreateProjectForm} />
              {this.state.showForm && <ProjectForm {...this.props} /> }

              {this.state.projects.map((el,key)=>  
                          <Project key={key} {...this.props} project={el} />)}

            </div>
      )
  }
}
export default Projects
```

Project Reducer for creating

```
function projectReducer(state={}, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case projectActions.GET_PROJECT:
        {
            return {project:action.payload.data}
        }
        case projectActions.CREATE_PROJECT:
        {
            return {...state, project:action.payload.data}
        }
        default:
        {
            return state;
        }
    }
}

export default projectReducer
```

Project Actions

```
export function getProject(){
return (dispatch, getState) => {
      return Project.readProject()
                        .then((response)=> {dispatch(getProjectAction(response))})
                        .catch((error)=>dispatch(getError(error)))
}
}


export function createProject(p){
return (disp, getState) => {
      return Project.createProject(p)
                        .then(response=> {disp(createProjectAction(response))})
                        .catch((error)=>disp(getError(error)))
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.state={
        showForm:false,
        projects:this.props.projects
}
```

That's your problem.  You're assigning `this.props.projects` onto `this.state.projects` when the component is mounted.  This only happens once, on mount, and will not update.

If you simply want to pass data from props to a child, you can just do so;

```
{this.state.projects.map((el,key)=>
```

Should instead be

```
{this.props.projects.map((el,key)=>
```

And there's no need to set projects on state in the constructor anymore.

Comment: update: I've just tried it, and it now only show the newly created project and removes the rest of existing projects. I want new project to be added to the existing projects not replace them

Comment: That's what your reducer is doing though.  If you want to add to an existing piece of state, you'll need to do a `.push` on that array, instead of overwritting it with new data (which removes the old data).

Comment: Should I push data on the array in the reducer?

Comment: The reducer is the correct place to make those kinds of data manipulations.

Comment: I've tried to add items to the array as  `{...state, project:[...state.project, action.payload.data]}` it worked. it adds the component to the rest of exisiting projects but the name/description of projects aren't showing up since now its an array within an array. any tip?